# window.open won't work in Phonegap 1.7.0

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-ui, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm working with Phonegap on a mobile device. And its issues and bugs are too much to solve. One of them is:

```
window.open('new_window.html','well','width=300,height=200');
```

> (I have already created a new_window.html under assets/www/.)

it appears a full screen window, and of course. If I set scroll bar option is true, it's still no use. The system is like a dummy.

I have searched the solution for several days, trying use iframe/frame to replace it. But they are not appropriate or no use. In my development environment, I just want to let the user press a button and a small window pops out. I can set the tile, location, size... 
Any alternatives or suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting the size on the actual page that is popping up and try window.open() again, if that does not work try:

```
window.location.href = "newindow.html";
```

If that does not work either and you could try using a jQuery Dailog box (need to import the jQuery Library found here [jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/home)) as the popup, code would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#buttonID').click(function() 
    {
        $help.dialog('open');
        return false;
    });

    var $help = $('<div></div>')
        .html('Your HTML copy goes here!')
        .dialog
        ({
            autoOpen: false,
            height:200,
            width: 300,
            title: 'Window Title'
        });
});
```

Comment: Only jQuery can work... But it still can't work properly, some attributes like "position" is invalid at all. Still thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are treating it like a web browser when it is not a web browser. You can use the ChildBrowser plugin from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser

Comment: Actually, I already installed ChildBrowser, but I can't set it's size and position. What I need is a small window, a pop-out window.